# Show only one month name in FullCalendar when WeekView wraps two different months

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, momentjs

I am developing using fullcalendar.js, and in the week view, when a week is from 2 different months (for example 27 july - 2 august) the fullcalendar week view shows the two months text. I am searching everywhere but there is no solution for this. Maybe stackoverflow users can help me.

### That's what I have:

[image: That's what I have]

### And that's what I need:

[image: That's what I need]

I see the date format but is **MMMM YYYY**, and it returns two months or one automatically and it seems impossible to change this.

In `Calendar.defaults` (aprox. line 8300 in non-minimized code) object I can notice this:

```
titleRangeSeparator: ' \u2014 ', // emphasized dash
monthYearFormat: 'MMMM YYYY', // required for en. other languages rely on datepicker computable option
```

As I explained, `monthYearFormat` seems to only be one month, but in a specific moment it merges with `titleRangeSeparator` to become two months.

Do you know how this is solvable?

Thank you.

## EDIT

I found the functions that make this complex string, but is used by month and day views that I don't want to change (I need only to week view). The code is the next. How can I modify this code to solve it?

```
// Date Range Formatting
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// TODO: make it work with timezone offset

// Using a formatting string meant for a single date, generate a range string, like
// "Sep 2 - 9 2013", that intelligently inserts a separator where the dates differ.
// If the dates are the same as far as the format string is concerned, just return a single
// rendering of one date, without any separator.
function formatRange(date1, date2, formatStr, separator, isRTL) {
   var localeData;

date1 = fc.moment.parseZone(date1);
date2 = fc.moment.parseZone(date2);

localeData = (date1.localeData || date1.lang).call(date1); // works with moment-pre-2.8

// Expand localized format strings, like "LL" -> "MMMM D YYYY"
formatStr = localeData.longDateFormat(formatStr) || formatStr;
// BTW, this is not important for `formatDate` because it is impossible to put custom tokens
// or non-zero areas in Moment's localized format strings.

separator = separator || ' - ';

return formatRangeWithChunks(
    date1,
    date2,
    getFormatStringChunks(formatStr),
    separator,
    isRTL
);
}
fc.formatRange = formatRange; // expose
function formatRangeWithChunks(date1, date2, chunks, separator, isRTL) {
var chunkStr; // the rendering of the chunk
var leftI;
var leftStr = '';
var rightI;
var rightStr = '';
var middleI;
var middleStr1 = '';
var middleStr2 = '';
var middleStr = '';

// Start at the leftmost side of the formatting string and continue until you hit a token
// that is not the same between dates.
for (leftI=0; leftI<chunks.length; leftI++) {
    chunkStr = formatSimilarChunk(date1, date2, chunks[leftI]);
    if (chunkStr === false) {
        break;
    }
    leftStr += chunkStr;
}

// Similarly, start at the rightmost side of the formatting string and move left
for (rightI=chunks.length-1; rightI>leftI; rightI--) {
    chunkStr = formatSimilarChunk(date1, date2, chunks[rightI]);
    if (chunkStr === false) {
        break;
    }
    rightStr = chunkStr + rightStr;
}

// The area in the middle is different for both of the dates.
// Collect them distinctly so we can jam them together later.
for (middleI=leftI; middleI<=rightI; middleI++) {
    middleStr1 += formatDateWithChunk(date1, chunks[middleI]);
    middleStr2 += formatDateWithChunk(date2, chunks[middleI]);
}

if (middleStr1 || middleStr2) {
    if (isRTL) {
        middleStr = middleStr2 + separator + middleStr1;
    }
    else {
        middleStr = middleStr1 + separator + middleStr2;
    }
}

return leftStr + middleStr + rightStr;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't directly supported unfortunately, but there is still a better way than modifying the FC source (that get's messy with patches and stuff).

There are several render hooks available that we can use to fix the formatting after the fact. [`viewRender`](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/viewRender/) doesn't work because it's called *before* the title changes. So we can use [`eventAfterAllRender`](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventAfterAllRender/) instead.

```
eventAfterAllRender:function(){
    if(view.name!=="agendaWeek")
        return;
    var $title = $("#calendar").find(".fc-toolbar h2"); //Make sure this is the right selector
    var text = $title.text();
    text = text.match(/.*? /)+text.match(/[0-9]+/);
    $title.text(text); //replace text
}
```

**[JSFiddle - titleFormat hack](http://jsfiddle.net/slicedtoad/kndy0s8a/3/)**

Not the most elegant thing in the world, but it should work better than modifying the source. Let me know if there are any issues.

Edit:

Also, if you're having problems with it flashing the wrong dateformat before the correct one, use css the make the title invisible. Then add a class to the element in `eventAfterAllRender` that makes it visible again.

Comment: Hey, this seems to be a good answer. I check it tomorrow morning and I worth your bounty. Thank you!

Comment: One question: where do I need to put this function?

Comment: @Marcos it's a fullcalendar option. Take a look at the fiddle

Comment: It seems that works, but It don't work. It's because the replace string. My calendar has `Month1 - Month2 2015` and not `Month1 - Month2 - 2015`. I am testing with other regexp.

Comment: I achieve it changing the replace function to this : `var text = $title.text().replace(/—.*[ ]/,' '); ` And now it works. Thank you very much!

Comment: Yeah, changing the regexp works. If you view how the text is written you can view why my regexp with a `[ ]` space into brackets

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude It works if you replace the `[ ]` with just a space, no?

Comment: Yes, to separate month of the year

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude I just noticed a mistake. If you change the date to the year rollover, you get "jan 2014 2015". I've updated my answer.

Comment: thank you very much to stay updated in your answer. All improvements are welcome, this is a real serious project and it must to be perfect-coded. If you notice something different please, tell me. You are worthy of the bounty of 100 points.